# How to use a next-auth jwt in relay-nextjs?

Tags: next.js, relay, next-auth

I am trying to use `next-auth` with `relay-nextjs`. I setup `next-auth` per [a hasura jwt example](https://github.com/praveenweb/next-auth-hasura-example/blob/main/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.js), and `relay-nextjs` per [the official docs](https://reverecre.github.io/relay-nextjs/docs/configuration#usage-in-a-page). I want to pass a `next-auth` jwt Bearer token in the `relay-nextjs` Authorization header sent  to the GraphQL endpoint.

1. `next-auth` provides a `getSession` method. [Under the hood](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/60fdf26a569937dd0b483f14ee35f398183b2d79/src/client/index.js#L140), this [requests](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/60fdf26a569937dd0b483f14ee35f398183b2d79/src/client/index.js#L297) a server endpoint.
2. `relay-nextjs` provides a `serverSideProps` property of a `withRelay` HoC. You pass your page component to `withRelay`. You add a function to `serverSideProps` that will send a token to the page's Relay environment.

My problem is `getSession` is null inside `serverSideProps`:

```
serverSideProps: async (ctx) => {
    const { getSession } = await import('next-auth/client');

    // This is an example of getting an auth token from the request context.
    // If you don't need to authenticate users this can be removed and return an
    // empty object instead.
    const token = await getSession();
    return { token };
  }
```

If I can get the token here, it works in `relay-nextjs`. Returning a string works fine, adds it to the header.

There's a `next-auth` cookie with the app page request. I checked it against the endpoint called by `getSession`. The cookies don't match. They do, until this part after the last dot, which changes on each request.

```
session-token=xxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxx
```

I ran it through the debugger, and it looks like `relay-nextjs` executes before the `next-auth` callback.

One approach I'm trying now is store the `next-auth` token in a database, and run a prisma query instead of `getSession`. Any input is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

ok this is a lot easier than I thought. Just do:

```
serverSideProps: async (ctx) => {

    // This is an example of getting an auth token from the request context.
    // If you don't need to authenticate users this can be removed and return an
    // empty object instead.

    return { token: ctx.req.cookies['next-auth.session-token'] };
  }
```

I traced through the next-auth code here:

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/77012bc00cd4247ee633777916ece31976b2f477/src/server/routes/session.js#L25

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/src/server/lib/cookie.js#L142

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/src/server/index.js#L66

Comment: Some links are broken, could you update them? Also I am curious: how did you setup this for client side relay environnement setup? relay-nextjs docs show something that doesn't rely at all on the session/(next auth useSession hook) and I am having a hard time to set this up properly. Thanks in advance for your help !